# how to Get stats from timeseries dataframes and impute it in 3rd dataframe based on certain rules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, quantitative-finance

i have two dataframes

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({"a":pd.date_range("2021-01-01","2021-01-10"),
         "b" :[12,13,16,15,12,14,17,19,20,21]})

df2=pd.DataFrame({"a":pd.date_range("2021-01-01","2021-01-10"),
               "b":[np.nan,np.nan,13.7,14.3,14,15,14.3,16.7,18.8,20]})
```

whenevr df1[b] > df2[b] i want to buy and whenevr df1[b] < df2[b] exit.

**Note:**

1. i wont take buy if previous buy did not exit
2. if buy happens and exit condition did not so we will consider last date as exit

**Required Output**

```
#dataframe 
stat=pd.DataFrame({"stock":["b","b"],
          "Entry_date":["2021-01-03","2021-01-07"],
         "Entry_price":[16,17],
         "Exit_date":["2021-01-05","2021-01-10"],
         "Exit_price":[12,21]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update (multiple stocks)

Given multiple stocks `b` and `c`:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':{0:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),1:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-02 00:00:00'),2:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-03 00:00:00'),3:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-04 00:00:00'),4:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-05 00:00:00'),5:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-06 00:00:00'),6:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-07 00:00:00'),7:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-08 00:00:00'),8:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-09 00:00:00'),9:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-10 00:00:00')},'b':{0:12,1:13,2:16,3:15,4:12,5:14,6:17,7:19,8:20,9:21},'c':{0:13,1:16,2:15,3:12,4:14,5:17,6:19,7:20,8:21,9:12}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':{0:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),1:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-02 00:00:00'),2:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-03 00:00:00'),3:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-04 00:00:00'),4:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-05 00:00:00'),5:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-06 00:00:00'),6:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-07 00:00:00'),7:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-08 00:00:00'),8:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-09 00:00:00'),9:pd.Timestamp('2021-01-10 00:00:00')},'b':{0:np.nan,1:np.nan,2:13.7,3:14.3,4:14.0,5:15.0,6:14.3,7:16.7,8:18.8,9:20.0},'c':{0:np.nan,1:13.7,2:14.3,3:14.0,4:15.0,5:14.3,6:16.7,7:30.0,8:30.0,9:30.0}})

# -------- df1 --------      ---------- df2 ----------
#             a   b   c                  a     b     c
# 0  2021-01-01  12  13      0  2021-01-01   NaN   NaN
# 1  2021-01-02  13  16      1  2021-01-02   NaN  13.7
# 2  2021-01-03  16  15      2  2021-01-03  13.7  14.3
# 3  2021-01-04  15  12      3  2021-01-04  14.3  14.0
# 4  2021-01-05  12  14      4  2021-01-05  14.0  15.0
# 5  2021-01-06  14  17      5  2021-01-06  15.0  14.3
# 6  2021-01-07  17  19      6  2021-01-07  14.3  16.7
# 7  2021-01-08  19  20      7  2021-01-08  16.7  30.0
# 8  2021-01-09  20  21      8  2021-01-09  18.8  30.0
# 9  2021-01-10  21  12      9  2021-01-10  20.0  30.0
```

First set the date as index and create the initial `df1 > df2` mask:

```py
df1 = df1.set_index('a')
df2 = df2.set_index('a')

mask = df1 > df2
```

To handle missing exit conditions at the end (as in stock `b`), append an extra line to `df1` and `mask`:

```py
# duplicate the mask's last row but with False values
# - if the last row originally was True, this closes the exit condition
# - if the last row originally was False, this has no effect
mask = mask.append(mask.tail(1))
mask.iloc[-1] = False

# duplicate df1's last row to match the mask
df1 = df1.append(df1.tail(1))
```

Index the `entry` points with `mask & ~mask.shift()` and `exit` points with `~mask & mask.shift()`:

```py
entry = (df1[mask & ~mask.shift().bfill()]
         .stack().reset_index(name='entry_price')
         .rename(columns={'a': 'entry_date', 'level_1': 'stock'}))

exit = (df1[~mask & mask.shift().bfill()]
        .stack().reset_index(name='exit_price')
        .rename(columns={'a': 'exit_date', 'level_1': 'stock'}))
```

Then [**`concat()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the frames:

```py
pd.concat([
    entry[['stock', 'entry_date', 'entry_price']],
    exit[['exit_date', 'exit_price']],
], axis=1).sort_values(by='stock')

#   stock entry_date  entry_price   exit_date  exit_price
# 1     b 2021-01-03         16.0  2021-01-05        12.0
# 3     b 2021-01-07         17.0  2021-01-10        21.0
# 0     c 2021-01-02         16.0  2021-01-04        12.0
# 2     c 2021-01-06         17.0  2021-01-08        20.0
```

---

#### Original answer (one stock)

Create a boolean `mask` and index the `entry` points with `mask & ~mask.shift()`:

```py
mask = df1.b > df2.b
entry = df1[mask & ~mask.shift().bfill()].rename(columns={'a': 'entry_date', 'b': 'entry_price'})

#   entry_date  entry_price
# 0 2021-01-03           16
# 1 2021-01-07           17
```

And index the `exit` points with `~mask & mask.shift()`:

```py
exit = df1[~mask & mask.shift().bfill()]
exit = pd.concat([exit, df1.tail(1)]).rename(columns={'a': 'exit_date', 'b': 'exit_price'})

#    exit_date  exit_price
# 0 2021-01-05          12
# 1 2021-01-10          21
```

Then [**`concat()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the frames:

```py
stat = pd.concat([
    entry.reset_index(drop=True),
    exit.reset_index(drop=True),
], axis=1).assign(stock='b').dropna()

#   entry_date  entry_price  exit_date  exit_price stock
# 0 2021-01-03           16 2021-01-05          12     b
# 1 2021-01-07           17 2021-01-10          21     b
```

Comment: will it work for multiple columns ? Say we do not only have b , but instead, we have 20 stocks dataframe

Comment: @Amit see the update for multiple stock support

Comment: i completed this problem using nested loops which was actually taking a while to execute .  this is awesome .